# I can't open my Web App Link on Google App Scripts when multiple Gmail accounts logged in

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Great day to you!.**

I have found an issues when open Web App with multiple Gmail accounts logged in as an image attached.

[image]

**My Web App link: https://script.google.com/macros/u/3/s/AKfycbzKLT0u7rE-hQbdJss2-1J-hyiWirkwUglfk6S8ColrARApgnFAJgyTStDf7pdxLCwp/exec**

After several searches on Google and Stack Overflow,

My current findings are:

1. Sign out all accounts and sign only one account ([Google Web App Multiple Google Accounts Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780096/google-web-app-multiple-google-accounts-error))
2. Open New Incognito Tab then sign in one account
   ([Google Web App Multiple Google Accounts Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66780096/google-web-app-multiple-google-accounts-error))
3. Create alert pop-ups(https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/home/announcements/multiple-accounts-issue-with-google-apps-script)

However, I think it's an extremely better if they can open Web App Link while they are logging in multiple Google accounts.

Therefore, my question is

**"How do we open Web App by Google App Script while Google accounts logged in?"**

Thank you.

Comment: The script editor and web-apps can be opened when signed-in in multiple accounts but it's true that under certain conditions they might not work as expected. If you are not able to open then your case is different than the one described on the linked page. Please 1) Focus your question in one , the script editor or the web app, 2) add a brief description of your search efforts (this means search this site for similar questions and whenever is possible add a link to the most relevant similar questions) and if your will focus the question in a web-app add a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, agree with you Rubén. Thank you for your help :). Have edited as you recommended.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] (include appscript.json, gs and if used html files)

Comment: It's about opening an Google App Script, not related to minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

### This is a well known issue and is [filed on Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/72798634)

While this issue is being worked on, unfortunately  the only feasiable workaround is toUnfortunately is to NOT being signed in with multiple accounts.

I also recommend you to "star" this issue on Issue Tracker to increase the visibility and hopefully accelerate fixing.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in the company I work for and we found a way to work around it. Maybe it is the same to you, or it could help someone else.

We had to access to our web app with the company account (g-suite accounts), but some of us had multiple accounts logged in. Basically, we needed to open the web app with a specific account, the one of our company domain.

Our solution was to log out all the accounts and then to start to log them in again, beginning with the account that have to access the web app. In this way, that account became the main account and it can finally open the web app, since they belong to the same domain.

This solved the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I encountered the same challenge when attempting to configure the script's settings to allow access to 'Anyone'.

### Making Your Script Accessible to Everyone?

Follow these steps to make your script open to Anyone.

#### 1. Archive Old Versions

Before you start, make sure to archive any old versions of your script. This helps avoid confusion if you have multiple versions (deployments) of the same script.

#### 2. Create a New Deployment

- **Go to Deployment Options**: Find the option in your script settings to create a new deployment.
- **Configuration**:

  - Set **Execute as Me** so the script runs with your permissions.
  - For access, choose **Who can access: Anyone**. This makes your script public.
- **Deploy**: You'll get a deployment link and a Web App URL that looks like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/XXXXXXX/exec`, where `XXXXXXX` is your unique script ID.

#### 3. Test Your Deployment

- **Use Incognito or Postman**: Test the Web App URL in an incognito browser tab or Postman. This ensures there are no issues related to account logins.
- **Ready to Share**: If the script works fine in the test, it's good to go.

#### 4. Share Your Script

With successful testing, your script is now ready to be shared with others.