google.script.run does not work, the function status goes to Paused until time out, Google apps Script
I'm currently developing a script to manage company resources using a Google Spreadsheet, where people would request a resource and inform a due date to it, when that date comes, an email is sent remembering the person to give it back. The script works fine when I'm using my account, the account in which I created the spreadsheet and wrote the script. However, when I share the script with another account (with editor authorization), every time the person runs the script, the google.script.run is called and the scripts show "paused" until the time out.
I've tried different deployment settings, and the same happens. I've also verified that the issue seems to reproduce only when the google.script.run is called through an HTML form I made on a sidebar menu.
Here is the current Code.gs:
/**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

function onOpen(e) {
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu("Menu")
  .addItem("Call Dialog from Menu", "teste")
  .addItem('Call Sidebar', "showSidebarForm")
  .addToUi();
}

function test() {

  Logger.log("Called")
  
  let ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert("title", "message", ui.ButtonSet.OK);

  Logger.log("Ended")
  
}

function showSidebarForm() {
  var userForm = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("test-form").evaluate().setTitle("Test Sidebar");

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userForm)
}

When I run the script logged on the "owner" account both logs Logger.log("Called") and Logger.log("Ended") are displayed on the logs. On the other hand, when I run with any other account, only the Logger.log("Called") is displayed, I don't see any reason for the code to Pause right after that line.
Here as follows is the HTML form that is displayed on the sidebar and calls the google.script.run.test():
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="test-button">Call Dialog from Sidebar</button>
  </body>
  <script>
    let button = document.querySelector("#test-button");

    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      google.script.run.test();
      
    })
  </script>
</html>

From what I understand it is not a code issue, because it works properly when I'm using the "owner" account, it seems to be an authorization issue of some sort, but the sidebar is displayed to the other users, and they can call the Test dialog through the Menu.
I'm using the deployment configuration: Execute as User accessing the web app, Who has access: Anyone with Google account.

Use the Logger.log() to determine where it  fails

So, from what I gather the issue lies within the displayApprover call. Does the alert message appear to the users?

@user27425627 When I'm using the account I used to create the spreadsheet and write the script, it displays the alert message as expected. When I use any other account, it does not work. When I go to the "execution" menu I see that the handleRequestEvent function was called, but the status stays as "Paused" for some reason.

Define the following in your question: 1. "Other users" - Are they editors of sheet or script or something else? 2. "Deployment" - Why was this deployed in the first place? Is this a webapp or a sidebar? 3. Any errors in the browser console, when ui has to show F12? IMO, Paused means the Ui is showing, but the user is not responding - from Google's server pov.. From the user pov, Ui may  not even be shown due to whatever reason.

@TheMaster 1. What I mean by "other users" is when I log in to other accounts to test if the script is working properly, the idea is that everyone I share the Spreadsheet with will be able to run the script with their own account. I share the document with the editor privilege; 2. It is a sidebar, but I want a function to run daily using a Trigger, I thought that for that to work, I would have to deploy the project (I'm new to Google App Script). 3. No, no errors are displayed on the console, I even tried using try {} catch but the execution is Paused, and no error whatsoever is displayed.

@TheMaster Yeah, I thought that the "Pause" status would be for some sort of waiting-for-input state, but the dialog is not displayed at all when testing the script logged to another account.


Delete the deployment. It is not needed 3. I meant the browser console on the client not  the apps script console. Try F12 on the browser... and see if anything different pops up when logging into a different account...Also, try a different browser, try incognito mode... disable extensions...


When I open the sidebar, the following log is displayed dropping postMessage.. was from unexpected window. Also, an object is displayed with the following message Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit, Message = There was an error during the transport or processing of this request., undefined, but the sidebar opens normally. When I press the button that calls the google.script.run.test(), it displays Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY and nothing else. When I test with the account that works, after I interact with the dialog this message appears Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE,

@TheMaster It works fine when trying in incognito mode, no idea why, do you know about any limitation regarding having multiple Google accounts logged on the browser? Maybe it works only for the account registered as default on the browser?

multiple Google accounts logged on the browser Yes, there are known issues like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69684594/  Also, Although probably irrelevant to this issue, you might wanna add a failureHandler to google.script.run to catch and log any error messages, if it comes.
